# How to split one column into two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have one column called Car, witch have two different row values (Volvo and BMW). How can I split this column into two colums (for example: Car1 and Car2). And then store all the row-values of "Volvo" in the "Car1"-column and then store the "BMW"-values in the "Car2"-column.

It looks like this:

```
+-------+
|  Car  |
+-------+
| Volvo |
| Volvo |
| Volvo |
| BMW   |
| BMW   |
| Volvo |
| BMW   |
+-------+
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
+-------+------+
| Car1  | Car2 |
+-------+------+
| Volvo | BMW  |
| Volvo | BMW  |
| Volvo | BMW  |
| Volvo |      |
+-------+------+
```

I've tried a few things with SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX ect... But I am totally stuck right now.

Comment: why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. It's typically expected that you include a [repro](http://sscce.org) of your situation and include your attempted solution(s). Be specific about your problem. Currently your question just reads as a (rather vague) to do.

Comment: Even though it is a strange request, it is a valid question with data and table provided. Problem is that it is not easy to write an attempt for a query solving this problem. Not fair to downvote.

Comment: @zahorak why do you even care?

Comment: If that last table was the whole deal (as `SELECT *` suggests), the 2nd Volvo row is redundant.

Comment: I think @zahorak is right. There'e good reason to do sth like this. SQL does not work this way. If you follow this path, only pain you will find.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you asked for. Is it really what you want ? This solution will also work for more than 2 car labels.

```
;with x as
(
select distinct car, dense_rank() over (order by car desc) rn from car
)
select @carlist = coalesce(@carlist + ',[' + car+']', +'['+ car+']'),
       @carlist2 = coalesce(@carlist2 +','+ car + ' Car' + cast(rn as varchar(4)), car + ' Car1')
  from x
  order by rn

declare @sql varchar(max)=
';with x as
(
 SELECT car, row_number() over (partition by car order by car) rn
 FROM car
 )
SELECT '+@carlist2+'
FROM  
x 
PIVOT (max(car) FOR [car] IN ('+@carlist+')) AS pvt'

exec(@sql)
```

Result:

```
Car1  Car2
Volvo BMW
Volvo BMW
Volvo BMW
Volvo NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try this !

```
;with cte as
(
select case when car='volvo' then 'volvo' else 'BMW' end as bekar from t 
)

select case when bekar='volvo' then 'volvo' else '' end as Car1,
        case when bekar='BMW' then 'BMW' else '' end as Car2
from cte
```

### [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/475dc/5)

Comment: -1 this answer does not give the same result as requested. It also suggests that any car which is not a volvo is a bmw